# Weird behaviour when querying data from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write some data in firebase database, however i got the wrong running process. Could somebody help me with it? Many thanks!!

The JSON tree structure is like as follows:

```
{ 
    "cars": {

        "auto id": [

            "parts": "wheel"
             ...
    .
    .
    .



@objc func buttonTapped(){

    print("before running")
        var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "cars").queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            autoId = snapshot.key
            print("running")
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
print("after running")
let newPlanetRef = Database.database().reference().child("company").childByAutoId()
                    newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)
}
```

I expect the running process is

> "before running"->"running"->"after running"

But the actual process is

> "before running"->"after running"->"running"
>   And the data cannot be updated to database unless I put the update function inside the closure

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous and data returned from Firebase is only valid *within the closure* following the function. Read the [Firebase blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) on the topic. Can  you better explain what you're attempting to do as the presented code is unclear. Note that code is faster than the internet so any code following the firebase call will execute *before* the data is returned from Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an async process.

You should use like this:

```
var newPlanetRef: String? //It should be your reference type

var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "cars").queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        autoId = snapshot.key
        newPlanetRef = Database.database().reference().child("company").childByAutoId()
        newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)
        print("running")
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

But I think use like this:

- Create private enum for your reference keys:

  ```
  private enum ReferenceKeys {
      static let carsKey = "cars"
  }
  ```
- Create global variables of your database references:

  ```
  var database = Database.database()
  var databaseReference = database.reference()
  var carReference = database.reference(withPath: ReferencesKeys.carsKey)
  ```
- Use your function like this:

  ```
  var newPlanetRef: String?

  var reference = carReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")

  reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in

      self?.autoId = snapshot.key
      newPlanetRef = databaseReference.child("company").childByAutoId()
      newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)

      print("running")
  }) { error in 

      print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  ```

---

**Bonus:**

You can use dispatchGroup (or semaphore) to wait snapshot value for proceed:

**DispatchGroup**

```
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    print("before running")
    var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "cars").queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { [weak self]snapshot in
            self?.autoId = snapshot.key

            dispatchGroup.leave()
            print("running")
    }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    print("after running")
    let newPlanetRef = Database.database().reference().child("company").childByAutoId()
    newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)
}
```

---

**DispatchSemaphore**

```
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    print("before running")
    var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "cars").queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { [weak self]snapshot in
            self?.autoId = snapshot.key
            semaphore.signal()

            print("running")
    }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    semaphore.wait()

    print("after running")
    let newPlanetRef = Database.database().reference().child("company").childByAutoId()
    newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)
}
```

---

**Completion**

```
@objc func buttonTapped(){

    getData { [weak self] snapshotKey in
        self?.autoId = snapshot.key
        let newPlanetRef = Database.database().reference().child("company").childByAutoId()
        newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(self?.autoId)
    }
}

/// completion type -(String?)- must be a snapshot.key's type
func getData(_ completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    print("before running")
    var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "cars").queryOrdered(byChild: "parts").queryEqual(toValue: "wheel")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            completion?(snapshot.key)

            print("running")
    }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print("after running")

}
```

Comment: Oh!! I got it, thanks for your help :)
Now i am wondering is there any way to force the process as I expected?

Comment: Hi @AlexChen, you can set completion to your function when snaphot value received you can call completion and set your autoId in completion of your function. Please mark as accept if it is works. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi again @AlexChen, please check my edit. I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: You probably know this but for clarity, `newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(autoId)` isn't valid; the autoId var in this case is a string and updateChildValues requires a key: value pair.